# Bash nested pipes and wildcards

Tags: bash, pipe

I have input files `foo1.txt`, `foo2.txt`, `foo3.txt`, etc. I have some command `munge` that processes the input files, but (for reasons that are not relevant here) the command can only process one input file at a time. I want to combine the output into a single `out.txt`.

I know I can do `cat foo*.txt` to concatenate all the input files, but as mentioned `munge` can only work on each separate file. That is, `munge` will not like it if I do `cat foo*.txt | munge > out.txt`. Instead I need to perform the processing on each file *before* the outputs are concatenated.

I'm sure I could loop over the input files using `for`, but then how could I combine the output?

Basically I'm looking for something like the equivalent of this, without enumerating all the input files beforehand.

```
cat foo1.txt | munge > out1.txt
cat foo2.txt | munge > out2.txt
cat foo2.txt | munge > out2.txt
cat out*.txt > out.txt
```

I'll bet there is some extremely simple command that can do this for me in a single line, perhaps with nested piping and wildcards. Any ideas?

Comment: What's wrong with a loop and >> ?

Comment: That's an interesting option, but it's not really piping the various outputs of `munge` to a single sink, Instead this would just append the various `munge` invocations to a single file. So if I ran the command multiple times, it would append the same contents to `out.txt`, over and over. I'd have to prepend the entire command with `rm out.txt &&`, wouldn't I? I think I could make it work, but maybe there is something more elegant.

Comment: Why would it append the same contents? The loop will pass a different input file to munge each time.

Comment: You missed the part of "if I ran the command multiple times". In other words, each time I ran the command, it would append to the existing file again, without erasing what was in the file to begin with (unless I manually delete the file first, as I indicated).

Comment: Ah right. You can empty the file before the loop with `> out.txt`

Answer (score 5):

Use a loop and redirect the output of the whole loop to `out.txt`. And there's no need to pipe from `cat`, you can simply redirect input to the file.

```
for file in foo*.txt; do
    munge < "$file"
done > out.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have useless uses of cat (UUoC):

```
cat foo1.txt | munge > out1.txt
cat foo2.txt | munge > out2.txt
cat foo3.txt | munge > out3.txt  # I assume you wanted 3 here
cat out*.txt > out.txt
```

is done more simply as:

```
< foo1.txt munge > out1.txt
< foo2.txt munge > out2.txt
< foo3.txt munge > out3.txt
cat out*.txt > out.txt
```

More usually, all redirections appear after the command, but this is not required:

```
munge < foo1.txt > out1.txt
munge < foo2.txt > out2.txt
munge < foo3.txt > out3.txt
cat out*.txt > out.txt
```

In Bash, process substitution could be used to combine these together, like this, but that would be overcomplicated when the final combinator is just catenation:

```
# useless use of process substitution plus cat (uuopspcat)
cat <(munge < foo1.txt) <(munge < foo2.txt) <(munge < foo3.txt) > out.txt
```

This can be done instead: run the programs in a subshell via the parentheses operator, and redirect the output of that subshell into the combined file.

```
(munge < foo1.txt ; munge < foo2.txt ; munge < foo3.txt) > out.txt
```

If `munge` is a "linear operator under catenation", loosely speaking, then it should be possible to do this:

```
cat foo1.txt foo2.txt foo3.txt | munge > out.txt
```

For instance if `munge` is something like `grep foo`, then this transformation is valid. Catenating the grep outputs is the same as grepping the catenated inputs.

If `munge` can be extended to take multiple filename arguments and iterate over them, then it can just be:

```
munge foo1.txt foo2.txt foo3.txt > out.txt
```

Comment: Maybe I could have explained it better in the question when I said "etc." (which means "so on and so forth"), but there can be any number of `fooX.txt` files (e.g. `foo567.txt` and `foo568.txt`). Hence the reference to wildcards. It's not clear to me which of your examples will handle this scenario, sending the contents of the files sequentially to `munge`, and concatenating the results.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `munge` can take a file name argument:

```
printf '%s\0' foo*.txt | xargs -0 -n 1 munge > out.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build up out.txt incrementally:

```
: >out.txt # Make out.txt empty initially
for f in foo*.txt
do
  # Process one file and append it.
  munge <$f >>out.txt
done
```